# Why are the Excavator and Marshal badges being awarded constantly?

Tags: bug, status-completed

**Edit: This seems to be a network-wide issue. See: [Meta Stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280023/excavator-and-marshall-badges-are-being-awarded-over-and-over#280023)**

A few minutes ago a got a notification that I received an Excavator badge. This was kinda puzzling, because I already had one. Shortly after I received yet another one, which made me open the acoording badge page. It appears that this badge is awarded repeatedly to random users.

> [image]

This goes on for **12** pages. Some people are also getting Marshal badges.

Comment: It's seems cleared now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We just did a major revamp of how badges are awarded behind the scenes to drastically reduce the load on SQL Server. It now takes advantage of some pre-compute work we're doing to track badge progress in the profile.
>
> However, I screwed up 2 queries, specifically the text names of the badges that prevent duplicate awarding. I was thinking to myself earlier "hey, maybe we should pass these in" as part of the rewrite - but it's not quite so simple. I'll take another look at this soon but when we're not fighting fires from a SQL Server upgrade. The cardinality changes which hosed some of the bigger badge queries needed urgent attention here, which ended up as a major revamp and introduced the 2 errors reported here.

-- [Nick Craver](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/280028/155160)

Answer (score 0):

SE is currently experiencing some sort of badge-related issues. It is being worked on by the developers.